# PHP if else with modulo number

Tags: php

I have number from 1 until 200, number will be printed in a page, each page has a limit by 81. When reach 81 then print into the next page. 
This is output i want:

```
number = 200;
print number 1 - 81 in page 1
create new page
print number 82 - 162 in page 2
create new page 
print number 163 - 200 in page 3
```

How to do it in PHP?

Update:
I mean i just want to print like above. No need of size of paper.
Here's what i have done

```
$number = 200;
$limit = 81;
$page = ceil($number/$limit);
for($i = 0; $i < $page; $i++){
  echo "print number 1 - ". 200-81 ." in page".$i; // i'm stuck in here
}
```

Comment: implement pagination

Comment: What is your page size? DIN A4? Landscape or portrait mode? What's the page margin? Does your printer support PostScript? Do you need this for a color printer or black and white? Is the printer connected locally or via WLAN? What is the weight of the paper?

Comment: *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.* Just think and you might find a solution. We won't write code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Please add the PHP code that you've tried so far, and any errors you have received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
$number = 200;
$limit = 81;
$page = ceil($number/$limit);
for($i = 0; $i < $page; $i++){
    $start = $i*$limit+1;
    $last = ((($i+1)*$limit));
    $last = $last>$number?$number:$last;
    echo "<br>print number $start - $last in page".($i+1);
}
```